# Compare new value with latest in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to define a `var res = 500` then compare it with some other value and if the other value is bigger than LATEST `res`, then save it on `res`. The problem is, in every comparison JavaScript is using the initially defined value, mean `var res = 500`. How can I compare it with the latest value not the initial?

My codes: (Scroll on page. as you can see in red area, `res` repeatedly jump to 500)

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
      var px = window.scrollY;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar");
      var body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement;
      var res = 500;
      var pxd = px / 100;
      if (px > 500 && pxd === parseInt(pxd, 10)) {
        if (px > res) {
          res = px;
        }
      }
      if (px > 500 - html.clientHeight) {
        x[0].style.position = "fixed";
        x[0].style.bottom = "10px"
      }

      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML ="res:" + res;
    }
```

```css
.content {
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right
}

.sidebar {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  position: static
}
```

```html
<h1>SCROLL THE PAGE</h1>

<div class="content">

</div>

<aside class="sidebar">
  <p id="text" style="padding-top:400px">res:</p>
</aside>
```

Comment: just initialize your `res` variable outside the onscroll function

Comment: You need to define the variable var res = 500; outside of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote it, res is equal to 500 everytime that you scroll the page.

You just need to put

```
var res = 500;
```

Out of the window.onscroll function

Answer (score 1):

This is because you set `var res = 500;` on every `onScroll` event. You need to set `var res = 500;` outside of your `window.onscroll` function. See example below:

```js
var res = 500;
window.onscroll = function() {
      var px = window.scrollY;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar");
      var body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement;
      var pxd = px / 100;
      if (px > 500 && pxd === parseInt(pxd, 10)) {
        if (px > res) {
          res = px;
        }
      }
      if (px > 500 - html.clientHeight) {
        x[0].style.position = "fixed";
        x[0].style.bottom = "10px"
      }

      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML ="res:" + res;
    }
```

```css
.content {
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right
}

.sidebar {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  position: static
}
```

```html
<h1>SCROLL THE PAGE</h1>

<div class="content">

</div>

<aside class="sidebar">
  <p id="text" style="padding-top:400px">res:</p>
</aside>
```